# Regex (pcre) - Parse ini-like file, between different nested, unquoted delimiters

Tags: regex, parsing, pcre

View on Regex101: [click here](https://www.regex101.com/r/bW2xF4/1)

Given a heading, (maybe) a section name, and a field name, I want to read the field's value, somewhat similar to reading values from an `ini` file.

---

For example, for the file below:
**Given**: heading: `heading2`, section: (empty), field: `field1`
**Output**: `field names can be repeated among headings.`

Another example:
**Given**: heading: `heading2`, section: `anothersection`, field: `field2`
**Output**: `Regex is harder when I add an
@ in a multi-line string, or if I add
backslash-escaped characters like \" and \'.`

`What happens if I have an empty line in a string?`

`Also,
[this line]
isn't actually a section.`

Another example:
**Given**: heading: `aaaaaaa`, section: (empty), field: `bbbbb`
**Output**: (no output; specified heading, section, or field doesn't exist)

---

However, my file is different from an ini file.
While ini files also have sections, mine is like a series of concatenated ini files, with `@ ..` to separate them:

```
@ heading1
field1: "single-line strings are quoted only sometimes."
field2: "strings that span
multiple lines
are always quoted."
field3: this single-line string is unquoted.

@ heading2
field1: field names can be repeated among headings.
field2: "Regex is harder when I add an
@ in a multi-line string, or if I add
backslash-escaped characters like \" and \'.

What happens if I have an empty line in a string?

Also,
[this line]
isn't actually a section."
field3: this field comes after field2
[sectionname]
field1: the same field name under a different section.
[anothersection]
field1: a second section under the same heading
field4: field number four

@ heading3
field1: value value value value value
field2: "quoted string
quoted string
quoted string"
unique: unique field name
```

I want to be able to specify a heading, possibly a section name, and a field name.
If the field exists under the specified header name, capture the value in a group. I also want to match the entire heading, regardless of whether the value was captured or not.

I've gotten this far:

```
^@ heading2$[\s\S]*?^(?:field2: \"?((?<=\")[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*(?=\"$)|(?<!\").*(?!\")$)\"?$|)?$[\s\S]*?(?=@ [^\s]*?|\Z)
(with gm modifiers)
```

This does most of what I want, including handling multi-line strings and backslash-escaped quotes.

**However, I'm struggling with the following:**

- **Capturing text in between two different nested delimiters, ignoring quoted delimiters.**

  In my case, I'm struggling to ignore quoted `@ ..` signs and `[sectionname]`s.
- **Match the entire text between two delimiters, but search only the text between them.**

  In my case, searching for a field under a section/heading and not overshooting the search into the next section/heading if the field doesn't exist.

My current regexp only avoids overshooting into the next section/heading because I've used a lazy alternation enclosed in `^$`. However, I can't rely on empty lines only being before `@ ..`. If I have an empty line in a quoted value, I won't be able to search for any field that comes after it.

I get the feeling I'm using regex wrong. Help is appreciated!

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Whoops, forgot to say. I've updated my post, please see the edited post.

Comment: sorry i can't able to read your expected output. What actually the give part does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the feeling I'm using regex wrong.

Indeed! There's a much simpler way: you can use regex to **tokenize** that input, then use some code to make sense of it.

Here's a pattern for you (with `x`):

```
^@\s*(?<heading>\w+)\s*?$
|^\[(?<section>\w+)\]\s*?$
|^(?<field>\w+):\s*(?:"(?<quotedstr>(?:\\.|[^\\"]++)*+)"|(?<barestr>.*?))\s*?$
```

Now take a look at [this demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/dC4eB7/2):

[image: demo]

See how the different colors nicely match the different token types you can have. If you hover the text on regex101, it'll even tell you the token type (group name) and value in the tooltip.

Every match can be either:

- a heading
- a section
- or a field along with its value.

So just iterate over the matches keeping a state (the current heading and the current section), and you'll be able to apply whatever logic you want easily.